# Kotlin: How to convert image uri to bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin

Most of the answers are in Java  I manage to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810879/kotlin-how-to-convert-an-image-uri-to-bitmap-to-base64) solution in Kotlin but it didn't work for me. I also tried finding documentation but I couldn't find one
What I'm trying to do is to select photo from gallery and then I want to convert Uri to Bitmap and then save it to the Room Database.

I would like to have a code similar to that but in Kotlin

```java
Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
Imageview my_img_view = (Imageview ) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap
```

Comment: Android Studio automatically converts Java to Kotlin.

Comment: @m0skit0 Didn't automatically convert to me . Usually converts if I have more lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
val imageUri: Uri = intent.data;
val bitmap: Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(c.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageUri))
val my_img_view = findViewById(R.id.my_img_view) as Imageview 
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: What does the value c represent in c.getContentResolver()?

Comment: Context c or you can use this depending on what you are using if activity then this is fine

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 2022:

Since `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` is deprecated, here is another option (from within a Fragment):

```
val imageUri: Uri = intent.data
val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(requireActivity().contentResolver, imageUri)
val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
val my_img_view = findViewById(R.id.my_img_view) as Imageview 
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Java equivalent:

```
Uri imageUri = result.getData().getData();
ImageDecoder.Source s = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
Bitmap bm = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(s);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I use this code inside `registerForActivityResult`.